# Is there a vim plugin for semantics/syntax highlighting?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, semantics, vim-plugin

I have a question regarding if a vim plugin exists. I googled it and couldn't find anything so I thought maybe I used the wrong key terms in my search. Recently I read this article https://medium.com/p/3a6db2743a1e about semantic coloring where each unique variable/function/etc. name has one color assigned to it. So my question would be, is there a vim plugin that does this at least for C/C++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim variable syntax highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21383532/vim-variable-syntax-highlighting)

Comment: I think that's not what I want but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 4):

This idea is commonly promoted by Douglas Crockford, well-known JavaScript guru and maintainer of JSLint. He added the beginnings of this idea to JSLint [last year](https://plus.google.com/+DouglasCrockfordEsq/posts/FzKnHk96m2C). Since his proposal is in JavaScript and for JavaScript, I only know of this being available in JavaScript.

There is a [plugin](https://github.com/bigfish/vim-js-context-coloring) for JavaScript context coloring in vim. However, I don't believe anything exists for C/C++.

Comment: Hi Conner, thanks for your reply. Basically that's the idea if there would be only context coloring for C/C++. Thank you for your reply and basically giving me the correct names of this concept so that I can further search!