# How to get color for keywords in vi editor. ***NOT IN VIM***

Tags: linux, unix, vim, solaris, vi

I want to highlight keyword in colors in vi editor in Solaris UNIX. Is there any way to do that? right now all the keywords are in same color so I am facing problem in my coding.

Comment: Are you actually using `vi` or are you using `vim`? True `vi` may have no syntax highlighting available.

Comment: I am using vi. VIM is not installed on machine.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777938/no-color-option-in-vi-editor-on-solaris. If you want color, you'll need to install vim.

Comment: And when you have Vim installed, [here is how to enable syntax highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272501/vim-default-syntax-highlighting)

Comment: Are you sure vi is not really vim by another name?  To see the truth, try `vi --version` from a shell.  If you do have vim, and you want different colors for each keyword, then this question (different colors for different variables) may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21383532/vim-variable-syntax-highlighting/21389025#21389025

Comment: not getting any version info.

Comment: In Solaris 10 and older, `vi` is the classic version of the editor.  In Solaris 11 and later, `vi` is now a link to `vim`.

Answer (score 1):

Vi doesn't do syntax highlighting.

If your vi is really vi and not a symlink of sort to Vim, you'll need to install Vim.

If your vi is Vim disguised as vi, like on many systems, you *may* be able to enable syntax highlighting by issuing the following commands:

```
:filetype on
:syntax on
```

Some lightweight Vim builds may not have syntax highlighting built-in, though, so please tell us what's the output of `:version`.